# How to style jQuery Mobile content in a Knockout template?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am using KnockoutJS with jQuery Mobile. However, it doesn't seem to style any of the content within the template regardless of their data-role. I am assuming it is because it loads it as an ajax call and that will be after jQuery Mobile has done its initial styling.

Some of my templates are pretty input heavy so I have read that you *can* go through each element and tell jQuery to style them as their relevant type, but surely there must be a way to get it to just redo everything, or a page?

Comment: I have read that there is a form.refresh() method on its way soon, any idea on how long that would be? Is there also any way to defer the jquery mobile caching of the page. As my templates dont really change once loaded, so if I could just delay it until all templates are loaded then that would bypass my problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how soon you need this working, I wouldn't count on form.refresh() coming anytime soon.  From the [jQuery Mobile Blog](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/)

> We’re working on some exciting additions to the library including broader transition support, pushState and more. For the near term, we’re going to target the Beta 2 release within the next 2 weeks to get these click changes and other improvements into the stable release so the pace of releases will start being much more frequent.

While it's possible form.refresh() is coming with beta 2, that's at least two weeks away.  Until then, your best option is to go through each element and call the style method.  You can get a list of element styles here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/forms/plugin-eventsmethods.html  Simply call them without arguments to force jQuery mobile styling.  Example: `$("input[type='number']").textinput();`

Another method that will work (but should probably just be used as a last resort) is simply coding the html of your template so that the elements are already styled as jQuery mobile elements.  In other words, all that html that jQuery mobile adds, such as `<span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">`, put it in yourself.  Of course, this means your templates end up with a bunch of extra html and could get confusing to work with, so only do this if you have to.

Comment: Thanks, already seen this page, can I also refresh elements with role="fieldcontain" as I have some inline roles set too and this is where I couldnt find out how to refresh them... 2 Weeks isnt the end of the world to me, as I can just work with the rubbish styles for now. I wont be finished for about a month I think...

Comment: You *should* be able to refresh elements with `role="fieldcontain"`, provided they are form elements and you call the correct function on them.

Comment: Additionally, there's no guarantee that form.refresh() will be in beta 2, so don't count on it until/unless it's officially announced as a upcoming feature.  I believe someone wrote a simple form.refresh plugin and posted it on the jQuery mobile forums, but I can't find it right now, and it might be out of date.

Comment: Update: from the newest jQuery Mobile blog post: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/07/22/jquery-mobile-team-update-week-of-july-18th/ you will be able to trigger a 'create' event which will perform this function, once they release beta 2.  This is likely already in the latest jqmobile.  Example code (from the blog): `$( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page" ).trigger( "create" );`

Comment: oh brilliant, will check this out when beta 2 comes out and give you the answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to accept the previous answer, as the problem I mentioned would be solved by that.

HOWEVER! the issue I was actually experiencing was because I had a reference to Qtip within my javascript includes, and for some reason that was causing the added elements to not get injected correctly. I.e my footer navbars were not receiving the spans injected into the anchors etc.

As soon as I removed it, everything worked.